# How to unit test an Angular Service whose main responsibility is to redirect to a page outside of the application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've got a service whose primary responsibility is redirect to our login page, which is separate since we're doing login as a service.

```
function redirectToMembership() {
    var returnURL = $location.host();
    returnURL+="/#/Authorization";
    $window.location.href=EnvironmentConfigConstants.membershipURL + "?ReturnURL="+returnURL;
}
```

So what it does is it gets the current host and appends `/#/Authorization` to the end and then redirects to the membership URL with that as the returnURL.

Authorization is a state that will handle the session token and userID which are returned from membership.

My question is:

#### How am I supposed to unit test this?

I have a hunch that I need to spyOn $location.href and verify that it is called with the current location, but whenever I fire `membershipService.redirectToMembership`, phantomJS crashes.

So far this is what I have for tests:

```
describe('redirectToMembership', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn($location,'host').andReturn('localhost');
        spyOn($location,'port').andReturn(80);
        spyOn($window.location,'href');
    });

    it('should redirect to Membership (duh)', function () {
        var success = false;
        membershipService.redirectToMembership();
        expect($window.location.href).toBe('this');
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }) ;
});
```

However, this is giving me two errors:

`'undefined' is not a function (evaluating spyOn($location,'host').andReturn('localhost')')`

and `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'returnURL.indexOf')`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Mock $location service and return test value from host spy function, similarly mock $window service and test against the location.href against it after the function call has been made. Testing actual redirection should not be a concern of your service

Comment: Hmm, okay, that makes sense.  How do I do that?  I've never needed to mock either of those before

Comment: You can create mock objects using jasmine.createSpyObj or even as a plain js object and then override it via `$provide.value` in the test setup. something like `location = jasmine.createSpyObj('$location', ['host']);` `location.host.and.returnValue("testhostvalue");`

Comment: Okay, I tried doing that.  I updataed the OP with what I'm doing now, but it's still not working

Comment: You can only spy on a function.

Comment: added an answer with kind of pseudocode, i have not tested or anything but it should give you some ideas hopefully.

Comment: Any luck with the below answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to focus on why phantomjs crashes, but the idea here is that mock your dependencies instead of actual instances, i.e mock `$location` and `$window` and have then return value as your test expectation. How the redirection happens, how host is returned etc.. should not be a concern for your service so just mock them out.

Something like this:

```
describe('redirectToMembership', function () {
    var $location, 
        $window = {location:{href:""}}, 
        host="localhost", 
        port="80",
        membershipService,
        $rootScope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        //Set up mocks
        module('myModule',function($provide){
           //create a spy object with 2 functions
           $location = jasmine.createSpyObj('location',['host', 'port']);
           $location.host.and.returnValue(host);
           $location.port.and.returnValue(port);
           //Set the mock object created above
           $provide.value('$location', $location) ;
           //Set the mock object
           $provide.value('$window', $window) ;
       });
       //get instances
       inject(function(_membershipService_, _$rootScope_){
           membershipService = _membershipService_;
           $rootScope = _$rootScope_; 
       });
    });

    it('should redirect to Membership (duh)', function () {
        var success = false;
        membershipService.redirectToMembership();
        expect($window.location.href).toBe(ExpectedContructedURL);
        $rootScope.$digest(); //You may not need this
    });
});
```